# kendoui scheduler - insert multiple appointments in the "edit" event

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

in the "edit" event of the scheduler (where i've customized the edit template) in need to
ingore the current edit event and insert programmatically multiple appointments

i've tried in this way

```
editable: { 
     template: $("#customEditorTemplate").html(),
},
edit: function(e){
                    
                    if(e.event.isNew()){
                        
                        //get formcontrols referenece 
                        var title = e.container.find("[name=title][data-role=textbox]");
                        var start = e.container.find("[name=start][data-role=datetimepicker]");
                        var end = e.container.find("[name=end][data-role=datetimepicker]");

                        ... other code
                        ..
                           
                           
                        //set formcontrols value    
                        $(title).data("kendoTextBox").value(sTitle);
                        $(start).data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(startTime); //set start date to the current date and time
                        $(end).data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(endTime); //set enddate to the current date and time


            //when click on save i need to insert not the current event but multiple event that i prepared programmatically
                        this.one("save", function(e) {
                            
                            e.preventDefault();  

                            var x1 = { 
                                "start": new Date(2023,3,28,12,00,00),
                                "end": new Date(2023,3,28,18,00,00), 
                                "title": "x1", 
                            };
                            schedulerDataSource.add(x1);
                            
                            var x2 = { 
                                "start": new Date(2023,3,29,12,00,00), 
                                "end": new Date(2023,3,29,18,00,00), 
                                "title": "x2", 
                                 
                            };
                            schedulerDataSource.add(x2);
                            scheduler.cancelEvent();  //remove/abort the current event
                            scheduler.refresh();  //doesn't work, doesn't refresh the scheduler

                            

                        });


                    }

                },
```

this doesn't show the x1 and the x2 event in the scheduler even if when the datasource sends data to the server added  events have been really added to the datasource

as note aside, on an external button click the code below works correctly showing me the new added appointments on the scheduler

```
schedulerDataSource.add(event);
scheduler.refresh();
```

I can't provide a live example but this is a full raw pastbin of the page
[the raw page](https://pastebin.pl/view/56b5ca44)

Comment: The [above sample works](https://dojo.telerik.com/OxicosAb) when I test it - double click to add an event and hit save. The two events are shown and the one created is not being displayed. But the dataSource is not synced. If I call `schedulerDataSource.sync()` the two programmatically added events are then submitted.

Comment: @Aleksandar thanks a lot, it's exactly what i need and your sample works like i expect! Nevertheless, my code doesn't work. No console errors, but x1 nor x2 events are showed, even if the two events are present into the datasource and are sent to the server later. maybe there is something else in my code (not in the `edit` event) that makes noise. Unfortunately can't provide a live example because my code is too coupled to the backend

Comment: i've added the raw page